# how to use Oracle group function count and group by clause for this query

Tags: oracle

```
Create a query to display the total number of employees and, of that total, the number of
employees hired in 1995, 1996, 1997, and 1998. Create appropriate column headings.
```

[image]

Suppose Employee table has following fields

1. emp_id number
2. firstname varchar
3. hire_date  date
   etc

Comment: Show us your table def ( DDL ), your existing data, and your SQL if you have any SQL yet.  Otherwise we are blind and cant help you.

Answer (score 1):

this might help!. Replace year as per your need

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) "Total",
  SUM(DECODE(hire_date,'2010',1,0)) "2010 Count" ,
  SUM(DECODE(hire_date,'2015',1,0)) "2015 Count",
  SUM(DECODE(hire_date,'2014',1,0)) "2014 Count"
FROM emp;
```

Comment: yes, this is exactly i want .i change my query like this--

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) "Total",
  SUM(DECODE(to_char(hire_date,'YYYY'),'2010',1,0)) "2010 Count" ,
  SUM(DECODE(to_char(hire_date,'YYYY'),'2015',1,0)) "2015 Count",
  SUM(DECODE(to_char(hire_date,'YYYY'),'2014',1,0)) "2014 Count"
FROM emp;